# What is (self) in the python code? (OOP question)

Tags: python, model-view-controller, oop, controller, pylons

```
class MyController(BaseController):

    def index(self):
        # Return a rendered template
        #return render('/test.mako')
        # or, return a response
        return ''
```

Why does the function "index" have "self"?

I got this code from Pylons controller

Comment: Duplicate of all these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+self.  Specifically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a member function (a function that's part of a class), so when it's called, the object it was called on is automatically passed as the first argument.

For example:

```
c = MyController()
c.index()
```

would call `index` with `self` equal to `c`. `self` is the standard name, but you can call it anything you want

Comment: Then can I use "self" inside the function "index"? print self.value

Comment: @alex Yes, if `MyController` has something named `value` (a field, function, etc.)

Comment: If I declare a class, and then I put functions inside it, can I put "self" as an argument in every one of those functions? Is it recommended to have "self" as the first argument for all of them, followed by other arguments?

Comment: @alex If they're not static or class methods (by default they're not), Python will pass the instance as the first argument, so you need to have a variable there to receive it, you can't skip it. You should probably read the [Classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) section of the Python tutorial

Answer (score 3):

Many languages, like C++ and Java, have an implicit pointer inside member functions.  In those languages, it is "this".  Python, on the other hand, requires an EXPLICIT name to be given to that pointer.  By convention, it is "self", although you could actually put anything you like in there as long as it is a valid identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a method in an object is called, the first parameter passed into that method is the object itself.  If you do not define the first parameter as being the object you are using, you will get a TypeError exception.